# How to store elements with whitespace in an array?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, whitespace

Just wondering, assuming I am storing my data in a file called BookDB.txt in the following format :

```
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.52:5:6 
Java for dummies:David:10.65:4:6
```

whereby each field is seperated by the delimeter ":".

How would I preserve whitespace in the first field and have an array with the following contents : **('C++ for dummies' 'Java for dummies')**?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @user000001, Good point. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ploutox's solution is almost correct, but without setting IFS, you will not get the array that you seek, with two elements in this case.

**Note**: He corrected his solution after this post.

```
 IFS=$'\n': arr=( $(awk -F':' '{print $1 }' Input.txt ) )
 echo ${#arr[@]}
 echo ${arr[0]}
 echo ${arr[1]}
```

Output:

```
2
C++ for dummies
Java for dummies
```

Comment: ahaha I was editing my answer but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I wouldn't use `IFS=$'\n';` though, but rather `IFS=$'\n':`. The version with `;` will allocate the value to your IFS varaible for the duration of the script, and might cause other following functions to misbehave, whereas the one with `:` will only allocate it for the line

Comment: @Ploutox, Thanks, verifying and editing. By the way, I think you are still missing an `=` in your answer.

Comment: Guys.... I dont know why, I get an array with the correct number of elements (2), but the wrong values. First element is 15 and second one is 16

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo, Is your input file **exactly** as you have shown? Also, you should un-accept this answer until it or another answer resolves your question.

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo, Also if you copied and pasted from the answer above, and your file is not named `Input.txt`, then you will also have a problem. :P

Comment: Okay I got it already thanks! Made a stupid mistake of adding # when echoing the first and second elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create and populate the array
a=()
while IFS=':' read -r field _
do
    a+=("$field")
done < file

# print the array contents
printf "%s\n"  "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally misunderstood your question on my 1st attempt to answer. awk seems more suited for your need though. You can get what you want with simple scripting :

```
IFS=$'\n' : MYARRAY=($(awk -F ":" '{print $1}' myfile))
```

the -F flag forces `:` as the field separator.

`echo ${MYARRAY[0]}` will print :

```
C++ for dummies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ yes sed -i "s/:/\'\'/" BookDB.txt | head -n100 | bash
```

this command while work. this is a linux command, run it on shell in same path with BookDB.txt