# Bash - how to ignore first delimiter of each line?

Tags: arrays, bash, delimiter

I have a file `BookDB.txt` which stores information in the following manner :

```
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.67:4:5
Java for dummies:David:10.45:3:6 
PHP for dummies:Sarah:10.47:2:7
```

How do I ignore the first delimiter of each line and add the first 2 fields into an array? (Refer to example below).

Assuming that at runtime, the script asks the user for the variables `TITLE` and `AUTHOR` respectively. How would I then store the combined fields into an array?

Eg :

```
ARRAY=('C++ for dummies:Jared' 'Java for dummies:David' 'PHP for dummies:Sarah')
ARRAY=($TITLE:$AUTHOR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570102/how-to-store-elements-with-whitespace-in-an-array), and it would have been beneficial for you to link it.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570666/391161) there can be modified to handle this quite easily.

```
IFS=$'\n'; arr=( $(awk -F':' '{print $1 ":" $2 }' Input.txt ) )
```

Note that there is no need to *ignore* the first delimiter to solve this problem. It suffices to acknowledge it and incorporate two fields instead of one.

Comment: ${arr[0]} = C++ for dummies

Comment: ${arr[1]} = Jared, ${arr[2]} = Java for dummies. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo, Checking.

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo, I made a one-character change. Changed the colon to a semicolon. I am not sure why it doesn't work with a `:` but it does with work `;`. Please verify.